# How to pickle in Client and Unpickle in Server?

Tags: scala, python-2.7, client-server, scala-pickling

I have a client scala code like the below

```
import java.net._
import java.io._
import scala.io._
import scala.pickling._        
import scala.pickling.json._  
val sk = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 13373)
val output = new PrintStream(sk.getOutputStream())
val textRDD = sc.textFile("some file");
output.println( #pickle the textRDD and pass it to server)
output.flush()
sk.close()
```

and python server.py like below,

```
import SocketServer
import json
import pickle
class MyTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer):
allow_reuse_address = True
class MyTCPServerHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
def handle(self):
    try:
        data = self.request.recv(1024)       
      #unpickle the data received here and print it.
        print data
    except Exception, e:
        print "Exception wile receiving message: ", e
server = MyTCPServer(('127.0.0.1', 13373), MyTCPServerHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

How to pickle the TextRDD file in the scala client and pass it to python server to unpickle it and print the received data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do this without rewriting scala-pickling in Python first. scala-pickling is Scala-specific serialization library, it is not even intended to be able to serialize/deserialize arbitrary formats; it is designed to be used as a substitute for Java serialization - fast and precise serialization for internal purposes.

If you need to send data across different languages, you should consider using portable protocols and serialization formats, for example, [Protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf), [Cap'n'Proto](https://capnproto.org/), [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) or [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/). For most of them there are multiple libraries in different languages, including Java/Scala and Python.

Comment: Consider a Scala server instead of Python server. Now, no cross platforms. Scala client to Scala server, is it possible in this case?

Comment: Yes, if you use Scala server, then it becomes much easier - just use whatever facilities scala-pickling provides for deserialization on server side. Several examples on how to do that are available on [scala-pickling](https://github.com/scala/pickling) page.